# excel performance using Range

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I'm now working on a project where speed is absolutely everything. So as I'm writing the code, I noticed a lot of the cells in the sheet are named ranges and are referenced in the functions explicitly like this:

```
function a() 

    if range("x") > range("y") then

    end if

    ... (just imagine a lot of named ranges)

end function
```

My question is, should i modify these functions so that the values in these named ranges are passed in as parameters like this:

```
'i can pass in the correct cells when i call the function
function a(x as int, y as int) 

    if x > y then

    end if

    ...

end function
```

Will that speed things up a little bit? These functions are called almost constantly (except when the process is put to sleep on purpose) to communicate with a RTD server.

Comment: Not exactly, but if you can load all the ranges into an array and do the comparisons in the array that might be faster. Array processing is definitely faster than looping through a range, but I'm not sure if that applies in your case.

Comment: No, there's no blocks of ranges. They are basically all individual switches located all over the places in the sheets. So are you suggesting that using parameters is a better approach?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that, rather something else that doesn't apply. It sounds like a function would help with organization of these things all over the place, but it won't help with speed.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is much slower at making "connections" to your worksheet than it is at dealing with its own variables.  If your function refers to the same cell (or range) more than once then it would be advantageous to load those into memory before VBA interacts with them.  For example if `range("x")>range("y")` is the only time in the function that either `x` or `y` are referred to then it won't matter.  If you have `if range("x")>range("a")` and `if range("x")>range("b")` and so on then you'd be much better off starting your function with

```
varX=range("x")
varY=range("y")
```

and then working with the VBA variables.

It might seem that by parameterizing the function as your second example shows accomplishes my recommendation.  This may or may not be the case because Excel might just treat those variables as references to the worksheet and not as values (I'm not sure).  Just to be safe you should specifically define new variables at the beginning of your function and then only refer to those variables in the rest of your function.

To sum up the above wall of text, your goal should be to minimize the number of times VBA "connects" to the worksheet.